# Explicitly refer to public DBLink when schema owns a private one of same name?

Tags: sql, oracle, public, dblink

I'm working a migration project requiring an import of several `Oracle` database schema onto an existing database. This requirement has brought about an interesting conflict where I now have two [`dblinks`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/ds_concepts002.htm) with the same name:

- One is a **private** `dblink` which uses account `A` to access the `Foobar` database
- The other is a **public** `dblink` to the same `Foobar` database which uses account `B` for its access

`Global Names` is set to true so I cannot change the names of these `dblinks`.

---

I've already figured out through trial and error that when signed into schema that owns the private `dblink` that the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table@foobar;
```

will refer to the private `dblink` and not the public one. But for situations where I require the account `B` privileges, I cannot figure out how to explicitly refer to the public `dblink`.

Does anyone know of syntax I can use to refer to the public `@foobar`?

Comment: can you create a unique synonym for one of the dblinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Oracle documentation.

> Oracle first searches for a private database link in your own schema with the same name as the database link in the statement. Then, if necessary, it searches for a public database link with the same name.

I don't think this can be changed in any way. Not that I know of or found in documentation. You could create public synonym but that will work only if you need to access with `B` specific objects. Synonym can't be created for whole database link.

Wouldn't it be easier to turn `global names` to `False` on session level and create new link to `B` with otherwise invalid link name. If you change `global names` on session level only that session will be allowed to use new link.

Comment: Thanks for this quote... adding the link where you took that from: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements009.htm

Comment: From what I'm seeing, I would have to agree with your assessment. It appears that I'll need a work around to access both DBLinks. Thanks!